# Hololens Navigation using tap and hold gesture bug?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gesture, hololens

Using the InputManager prefab from the [HoloToolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloToolkit-Unity) asset and implementation code the user can tap and hold on a given object and then move their hand left or right (along the x-plane) to rotate the object along the Y axis or up and down (along the y-plane) to rotate the object on the X axis.

However there appears to be a bug. If the users gaze comes off the object, the rotation stops immediately until the users gaze returns to the object. Is this the intended functionality? If so, how does one preserve the current object being changed via the navigation gesture and allow it to continue being manipulated until the users hand leaves the FOV or the user releases the tap and hold gesture?

Goal is to utilize the tap and hold gesture but not require the users gaze to be locked onto the object during the entirety of them rotating it. This is quite difficult with small or awkwardly shaped objects.

Implementation code:

```
[Tooltip("Controls speed of rotation.")]
public float RotationSensitivity = 2.0f;

private float rotationFactorX, rotationFactorY;

public void OnNavigationStarted(NavigationEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log("Navigation started");
}
public void OnNavigationUpdated(NavigationEventData eventData)
{
    rotationFactorX = eventData.CumulativeDelta.x * RotationSensitivity;

    rotationFactorY = eventData.CumulativeDelta.y * RotationSensitivity;

    //control structure to prevent dual axis movement
    if (System.Math.Abs(eventData.CumulativeDelta.x) > System.Math.Abs(eventData.CumulativeDelta.y))
    {
        //rotate focusedObject along Y-axis
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -1 * rotationFactorX, 0));
    }
    else
    {
        //rotate focusedObject along X-axis
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(-1 * rotationFactorY, 0, 0));
    }
}
public void OnNavigationCompleted(NavigationEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log("Navigation completed");
}
public void OnNavigationCanceled(NavigationEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log("Navigation canceled");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call these methods:

```
    NavigationRecognizer = new GestureRecognizer();
    NavigationRecognizer.SetRecognizableGestures(GestureSettings.Tap);
    NavigationRecognizer.TappedEvent += NavigationRecognizer_TappedEvent;
    ResetGestureRecognizers();
```

This is for a tapped event, but doing the other gesutres is simple as adding the event callback for them and using an `|` OR selector on the `SetRecognizableGestures()` call.  e.g.

```
    NavigationRecognizer.SetRecognizableGestures(GestureSettings.Tap | GestureSettings.NavigationX);
```

Comment: I am confused. Does tap also register tap and hold? Are you using the OR ( | ) to combine the tap and hold and the X axis navigation into one?

Comment: @jtth `Tap` is separate from `Hold`, if you look at the GestureSettings enum, you'll see all of its possible values.  You can even set up a program to recognize all of them (although I am pretty sure that `Navigation_`, `NavigationRails_` and `Manipultation` are all mutually exclusive because they all rely on the same gesture, but are interpreted slightly differently.  And yes, in this case I am using bitwise OR to combined two gesture types (in this case, tap and nav-x).  It doesn't combine the gestures into a single event, it says "I am interested in events of these types..."

Comment: You would still need `NavigationRecognizer.NavigationEvent += ...` to get a callback. (X, Y, and Z are all handled by the same event)

Comment: So would this be implemented in a pre-existing script already attached to the InputManager prefab, such as GestureInput, or should I be implementing this in my own script above?

Comment: @jtth Should be in the same script you have in your question, inside `Start()` or `Awake()`, assuming it is a MonoBehavior attached to a game object. If it is not, then you will need a way to initialize it (i.e. the answer code goes in some function, `Init()` or a constructor that you call from some MonoBehavior's `Start()` or `Awake()`).

Comment: Ok, figured it out. Clear the stack on Navigation started, `InputManager.Instance.ClearModalInputStack();`, push the object the user is using navigation gestures on, onto the stack, `InputManager.Instance.PushModalInputHandler(gameObject);` then on navigation completed or canceled, pop it off the stack. `InputManager.Instance.PopModalInputHandler();` Added this to my own implementation script. This is possible as the InputManager prefab creates the stack for me so it made this rather simple.

Answer (score 1):

Draco18s answer is safer, but this solution works as well because 
the InputManager prefab implements a stack for us.

On Navigation started, clear the stack and push the object being 'Navigated' onto the stack,

`InputManager.Instance.ClearModalInputStack();` 
`InputManager.Instance.PushModalInputHandler(gameObject);`

On Navigation completed or canceled, pop it off the stack. `InputManager.Instance.PopModalInputHandler();`

Add this to your own implementation script, no need to adjust any pre-existing scripts on the InputManager.